# Determine if name in list A has perfect match, partial match, or is not found in list B?

Tags: excel

In Excel, I have two columns of property names. I need to determine if a name in Column A has a complete match, a partial match or no match in Column B.

Something beyond setting this up that is confusing me as well is what if there are multiple partial matches - I don't think it is reasonable to complicate this with a "best match" component, but I'm not sure how to deal with this part.

How can this be done?

Comment: Determining complete match or no match can be achieved easily enough with the `Match` function. Partial match is more tricky as it depends on how you define a partial match. Can you post sample data?

Comment: @Remnant What about looping that check through Column B?
Here is an example:
Column A name: Wyndham Bentley Brook/unit 2131
Column B will have many "Wyndham" and even the true match in column B will probably be just Wyndham Bentley Brook.

Column A data is not formatted properly so many partial matches will be slight variances.

Another example:
Column A: Polo Towers - Las Vegas, Nevada (300x2)
Column B: Polo Towers in Las Vegas

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Exact match**

Finding out if an exact match is available is easy - you can use the `MATCH`function for this:

```
=MATCH(B1,A:A,0)
```

will return you the row number in which B1 is found. Combine it with IFERROR to handle elements that do not have any match:

```
=IFERROR(MATCH(B1,A:A,0),"No exact match")
```

Alternatively, if you're only interested if there is a match, but not where, use the `ISERROR` function:

```
=NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(B1,A:A,0)))
```

**Partial match**

From your comment I understand that a "partial match" means the occurrence of the full string in column B as a substring in column A. You can use the `SEARCH`function for that. However, as search will only check the appearing in one cell, you need to combine it as an array formula:

```
=MATCH(FALSE,ISERROR(SEARCH(B1,A1:A100)),0)
```

Enter it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Also note that for performance reasons it is better to limit the range to search, i.e. instead of `A:A`, use `A1:A100` - or whatever your number of rows is.

Comment: @p.campbell THANK YOU!!!

This is extremely helpful and should do the trick perfectly.

I really appreciate the help!!!

Comment: @Wyatt: I assume you meant me, so: you're welcome! ;-) if it solved your problem, please mark it as the answer! :-)

Comment: Peter, an I right that your first two formulas are U.S. (commas) and the last is European (semicolons)?

Comment: @DougGlancy: Well spotted - thanks for pointing it out! I forgot converting the last formula. Fixed now!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to know how closely the values match, consider using the Fuzzy Lookup Add-in for Excel
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15011

This link below provides a demo:
http://www.k2e.com/tech-update/tips/431-tip-fuzzy-lookups-in-excel