# Adapt VBA Module to find partial match instead of exact match

Tags: vba, excel, compare, partial

The original module is useful when looking for exact matches, but now I need to find partial matches.

For example in the CompareRange there might be a value of 93472398742398-118 but somewhere within the selection the value is only 93472398742398. The CompareRange is several thousand rows and the selection is much smaller.

I found the original formula here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/213367.

```
Sub Find_Matches()
Dim CompareRange As Variant, x As Variant, y As Variant
' Set CompareRange equal to the range to which you will
' compare the selection.
Set CompareRange = Range("F1:F5126")
' NOTE: If the compare range is located on another workbook
' or worksheet, use the following syntax.
' Set CompareRange = Workbooks("Book2"). _ 
' Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("F1:F5126")
'
' Loop through each cell in the selection and compare it to
' each cell in CompareRange.
For Each x In Selection
    For Each y In CompareRange
        If x = y Then x.Offset(0, 1) = x
    Next y
Next x
End Sub
```

I also tried to adapt a formula that I found in one of the Stack Overflow answers:

[Determine if name in list A has perfect match, partial match, or is not found in list B?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15309214/determine-if-name-in-list-a-has-perfect-match-partial-match-or-is-not-found-in)

but Excel says there's an error in the formula.

```
=MATCH(FALSE;ISERROR(SEARCH(B1;A1:A100));0)
```

Comment: [**This**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swf8kaxw.aspx) might help you get started.

Comment: For your formula error, since it looks like you're in the U.S., replace the semicolons with commas.