# Search list A (names) finding all potential matches from list E (surnames)

Tags: excel, match, string-matching

Column A is a list of names in varying format e.g. "Mr A Smith", "Joe Bloggs" or "Mr Smith & Miss Bloggs". Column B contains postcodes to uniquely identify the person(s).

Column E is a list of surnames (from a different source) and Column F is an incomplete list of accompanying first names.

Initially I would like to find all names in Column A that match a surname in Column E, so for example, if "Smith" is an entry in Column E, "Mr A Smith" and "Joe Smith" are entries in Column A, then both entries from column A should be 'found' and associated with "Smith" from Column E.

Using the formula below (from: [Determine if name in list A has perfect match, partial match, or is not found in list B?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15309214/determine-if-name-in-list-a-has-perfect-match-partial-match-or-is-not-found-in)) only the row number for the first "... Smith" in Column A is shown. (Columns A and E both have over 9000 entries!)

```
=MATCH(FALSE,ISERROR(SEARCH(E1,$A$1:$A$9345)),0)
```

Would it be possible to use Column F (first names) in addition to Column E, to avoid finding false matches? e.g. "Mr A Smith" from Column A shouldn't be 'found' unless the first name (Column F) starts with an 'a' OR there is no first name (empty cell).

Cheers

Comment: Take a look at this and see if this helps:http://www.get-digital-help.com/2011/06/07/lookup-with-multiple-criteria-and-display-multiple-unique-search-results-array-formula/

Comment: Thanks @EStraka it does help, but rather than just searching for one person's name (first, middle and last name), I'd like it to search a list of names. Would it be possible to be to search for the next name in the list once the previous search has finished?